# functional dependencies vs type families

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies, type-families

I'm developing a framework for running experiments with artificial life, and I'm trying to use type families instead of functional dependencies. Type families seems to be the preferred approach among Haskellers, but I've run into a situation where functional dependencies seem like a better fit. Am I missing a trick? Here's the design using type families. (This code compiles OK.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.State (StateT)

class Agent a where
  agentId :: a -> String
  liveALittle :: Universe u => a -> StateT u IO a
  -- plus other functions

class Universe u where
  type MyAgent u :: *
  withAgent :: (MyAgent u -> StateT u IO (MyAgent u)) -> 
    String -> StateT u IO ()
  -- plus other functions

data SimpleUniverse = SimpleUniverse
  {
    mainDir :: FilePath
    -- plus other fields
  }

defaultWithAgent :: (MyAgent u -> StateT u IO (MyAgent u)) -> String -> 
  StateT u IO ()
defaultWithAgent = undefined -- stub

-- plus default implementations for other functions

--
-- In order to use my framework, the user will need to create a typeclass
-- that implements the Agent class...
--

data Bug = Bug String deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Agent Bug where
  agentId (Bug s) = s
  liveALittle bug = return bug -- stub

--
-- .. and they'll also need to make SimpleUniverse an instance of Universe
-- for their agent type.
--

instance Universe SimpleUniverse where
  type MyAgent SimpleUniverse = Bug
  withAgent = defaultWithAgent     -- boilerplate
  -- plus similar boilerplate for other functions
```

Is there a way to avoid forcing my users to write those last two lines of boilerplate? Compare with the version using fundeps, below, which seems to make things simpler for my users. (The use of UndecideableInstances may be a red flag.)  (This code also compiles OK.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances,
    UndecidableInstances #-}

import Control.Monad.State (StateT)

class Agent a where
  agentId :: a -> String
  liveALittle :: Universe u a => a -> StateT u IO a
  -- plus other functions

class Universe u a | u -> a where
  withAgent :: Agent a => (a -> StateT u IO a) -> String -> StateT u IO ()
  -- plus other functions

data SimpleUniverse = SimpleUniverse
  {
    mainDir :: FilePath
    -- plus other fields
  }

instance Universe SimpleUniverse a where
  withAgent = undefined -- stub
  -- plus implementations for other functions

--
-- In order to use my framework, the user will need to create a typeclass
-- that implements the Agent class...
--

data Bug = Bug String deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Agent Bug where
  agentId (Bug s) = s
  liveALittle bug = return bug -- stub

--
-- And now my users only have to write stuff like...
--

u :: SimpleUniverse
u = SimpleUniverse "mydir"
```

Edit: In trying to present a simple example, I omitted part of the motivation for my design.

The #1 role that the Universe class plays is serialising and deserialising agents, so I think it has to be linked to the Agent class. It also has `readAgent` and `writeAgent` functions. However, I wanted to ensure that the user couldn't accidentally forget to write an agent after modifying it, so instead of exporting those functions, I provide a `withAgent` function that takes care of everything. The `withAgent` function takes two parameters: a function that runs on an agent, and the name (unique ID) of the agent to run the program on. It reads the file containing that agent, runs the program, and writes the updated agent back out to the file. (I could instead just export the readAgent and writeAgent functions.)

There is also a `Daemon` class that is responsible for giving each agent its fair share of the CPU. So inside the daemon's main loop, it queries the universe for a current list of agents. Then, for each agent, it invokes the `withAgent` function to run the `liveAlittle` program for that agent. The daemon doesn't care what type the agent is.

There is one other user of the `withAgent` function: the agent itself. Inside the agent's `liveALittle` function, it might query the universe for a list of agents, in order a possible mating partner. It will invoke the `withAgent` function to run some sort of mating function. Obviously an agent can only mate with another agent of the same species (typeclass).

EDIT: Here's the solution I think I will use. Not type families or functional dependencies, but now I have to do something so that the compiler will know which `liveALittle` to call. The way I've done that is to have the user supply the correct `liveALittle` as a parameter.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Control.Monad.State (StateT)
import Data.Serialize (Serialize)
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

class Agent a where
  agentId :: a -> String
  liveALittle :: Universe u => a -> StateT u IO a
  -- plus other functions

class Universe u where
  -- Given the name of an agent, read it from a file, and let it run.
  withAgent :: (Agent a, Serialize a) => 
    (a -> StateT u IO a) -> String -> StateT u IO ()
  -- plus other functions

-- This method will be called by a daemon
daemonTask :: (Universe u, Agent a, Serialize a) => 
  (a -> StateT u IO a) -> StateT u IO ()
daemonTask letAgentLiveALittle = do
  -- do some stuff
  withAgent letAgentLiveALittle "a"
  -- do some other stuff

data SimpleUniverse = SimpleUniverse
  {
    mainDir :: FilePath
    -- plus other fields
  }

instance Universe SimpleUniverse where
  withAgent = undefined -- stub
  -- plus implementations for other functions

--
-- And now my users only have to write stuff like...
--

data Bug = Bug String deriving (Show, Eq, Generic)

instance Serialize Bug

instance Agent Bug where
  agentId (Bug s) = s
  liveALittle bug = return bug -- stub
```

Comment: Can every actor be used in every universe, or is it, as your code says, that each universe only is usable by one type of actor?

Comment: I don't mind if each universe is only usable by one instance of Agent, because the user can take advantage of algebraic data types to support more than one species of agent.

I had an approach using existential types that would allow multiple Agent instances to be used in a universe. However, [that approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842426/deconstructing-an-existential-type) was criticised (justifiably, I think) for being un-Haskellish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you are overcomplicating things. It's not *more* complicated to support every kind of actor in a universe, it's *less* complicated.

Just write your `Universe` class like so:

```
class Universe u where
  withAgent :: Agent a => (a -> StateT u IO a) -> String -> StateT u IO ()
```

Note that you don't have to use functional dependencies or multi-param type classes, because the `a` doesn't have to be brought into scope in the class head; it is brought into scope by `Agent a => ...`. This is also essentially what you are doing in your functionally dependent version, because even though you use `u a | u -> a`, that `a` doesn't actually get used in the class body; instead, the `Agent a => ...` shadows the outer `a`.

Comment: I've added some clarification to my question, above. The withAgent function reads an agent from a file. It will be invoked by a daemon that does not know or care about the type of the agent. If the files can contain different agent types, then the universe won't know the type of agent in a file, which means it won't know how to deserialise it. This is why I think that the Universe class can only support one agent typeclass. Er, unless I go back to wrapping agents in existential types.

Comment: But the agent transformation function (the first argument to `withAgent`) will be for a specific agent type, correct? I.e. I would call `withAgent eatBugFood "bug5"` where `eatBugFood :: Bug -> StateT SimpleUniverse IO Bug` where at least the actual agent type is specified (`u` could still be free/unspecified, for example)?

Then you can still call the correct `readAgent` function for that specific agent inside `withAgent`, which might seem like magic, but it will work.

Comment: The only situation in which you would still need to use type families or functional dependencies is if you actually want to enforce that every universe only contains one type of `Agent`. In the `Daemon` for example, you could just store the `liveALittle` functions of every loaded agent instead of the actual `Agent`s, making existential quantification unnecessary. You'd still need a nifty container for storing all loaded `Agent`s, though; probably involving the `Typeable` class.

Comment: I ended up using something very similar to your last suggestion (see the end of the edited question, above).

Answer (score 7):

### Type Families vs Multi Parameter Type Classes with Functional Dependencies

To answer the question in the title, Functional dependencies tend to be rather counter-intuitive, so it's more of a headache to get them working.
Type Families are much easier to use, and so much more intuitive for 
a functional programmer, that I would recommend you always try using them first (unless you absolutely need
the extra type parameter for making instances of some other class over which you have no control).

In your case, I'm not sure you need either, which is, I believe, why you're running into problems.

### What do your Universe classes and instances say?

Both the class definitions tie the user to using each universe once, whereas they might like to reuse a universe with a different agent type.

Let's look at what's going on in your Universe instances:

- Type Families: You make an instance by writing a lot of boilerplate just reusing a 
  standard set of functions wholesale. This suggests you didn't need to know the particular type
  of MyAgent to deal with it. There doesn't seem to be an Agent context on any of the functions. Hmmm.
- Functional Dependencies: you use `instance Universe SimpleUniverse a where...` and magically 
  your `Agent Bug` instance gives you a working Universe. That's because your instance declaration 
  used the type `a` so at the matching end of the equation, didn't use any facts about `a`.

This leads me to suspect you don't need to link the universe and the agents so strongly. 
Suggestion 1: Is it possible to have two separate but linked classes:

```
class Universe u where
   withAgents :: Agents a => (a -> StateT u IO a) -> String -> StateT u IO ()
```

Here you're saying the universe has to accept *any* Agents type, not one *specific* Agents type.
I've renamed Agent to Agents to suggest to the users that they use it to represent *all* their agent types
in a union type as you pointed out.

```
class Agents a where
   agentId :: a -> String
   liveALittle :: Universe u => a -> StateT u IO a
```

Here you're saying an Agents type has to be able to interact with any sort of universe.

### The nature of the universe

The fact that you feel you can write default declarations like

```
defaultWithAgent :: (MyAgent u -> StateT u IO (MyAgent u)) -> String -> StateT u IO ()
```

or declare an instance that doesn't use any information about Bug:

```
instance Universe SimpleUniverse a where
    withAgent = ...
```

suggests you can write `withAgent` without reference to the types `u` or `a`.

Suggestion 2: Can you ditch the Universe class altogether in favour of either a TheUniverse type
so you define

```
withAgent :: (Agents a => a -> StateT TheUniverse IO a) -> String -> StateT TheUniverse IO ()
```

which I'm not convinced will suit you, or...

Suggestion 3: Ditch the Universe class restriction altogether, and make `withAgent` work with *any* type.

```
withAgent :: (Agents a => a -> StateT u IO a) -> String -> StateT u IO ()
```

It's hard to say what's best without knowing what other functions you need, but hopefully one of these might help.
I only make suggestions 2 and 3 because you seemed to be saying a default definition always works. 
Maybe in reality some functions need to be in the Universe class becuase they use the structure of the universe but not the internal details of the Agents. Maybe others belong in Agents because although they use a Universe, they just use class functions, not the internal details. In any case we have:

### Overarching suggestion:

Think carefully about what level of detail about a Agents or the Universe the function needs. If it's both, maybe you could refactor into two separate helper functions, so no function needs to know the inner workings of both the Universe and Agents. That way you don't need a type class that has both types. There'd be no need for either TypeFamilies or FunDeps.

Comment: You've given me some good food for thought. I've added some clarification to the end of my question, but I will look at other options for the design, taking your suggestions into account.