# Can't use list of typeclasses inside data declaration

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm new to Haskell and I like the programming approach of it a lot!

I've been running into this problem for the past 2 days, and no matter what I try, it refuses to work. I think I am confusing something about the nature of Haskell.

Here is my code (that doesn't work):

```
data Part = Part {partName :: String, events :: [Event]}

class Event e where
   getChildren :: e -> [e]
```

This is for a music application. `Event` can be a `NoteEvent`, a `DecrescendoEvent`, a `VolumeEvent`, a `KeyEvent`, or anything that would "happen" in a piece of music.

A `NoteEvent` would have no children while a `DecrescendoEvent` would have child events that it would gradually reduce the volume of.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that a sequence like [a] can only contain one type. There are two ways to deal with this.

1) Combine all your events into a single algebraic datatype, which might look something like this:

```
data Event = NoteEvent {note :: Int; duration :: Int} 
             | DecrescendoEvent {getChildren :: [Event]} 
             | VolumeEvent {change :: Double, getChildren :: [Event]}
```

...and so on. Now you can work with data of type [Event]. You can include the children like this:

2) Wrap the Event type in some sort of "wrapper" type, and create collections of *that* type. See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections for more information on this.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track! I'm going to try developing a wrapper that won't force me to maintain a dictionary of all of the `Event`'s that I have to convert. I'll post it when I'm finished.

Comment: Before you go to far down the "wrapper" road, let me suggest that you give some thought to what you're going to _do_ with the array elements. You'll only be able to use the functions defined for the wrapper type unless you go through some major gymnastics. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842426/deconstructing-an-existential-type and learn from _my_ mistakes.

Comment: We'll probably be able to give you better advice if you tell us a little more about what you're trying to do. Once you've got all of your events in a list, are you going to process them in some way? Are you trying to serialise/deserialise events? (Also, is this a MIDI application? If so, one of the existing Haskell packages might be useful.)

Comment: I'm planning on using the `Part`s to serialize into both Midi output and to a GUI structure (sheet music). If the GUI doesn't work out, I've been designing my own text-based music language that I want to parse into these data structures. I'll check out the Haskell package though.

Comment: You have the best answer so far, so might as well make it so.